# taking screenshot of multiple screens with QDesktopWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot

I'm using Qt-5.2 and Win7.

The application uses two monitors and I would like to take a screenshot that contains both screens.
QGuiApplication::screens() gives back the list of the two QScreen objects, and when I took screenshot of the primary screen, then it was OK. But now I need a screenshot of both, so QDesktopWidget seemed to be a good choice. The QDesktopWidget object is a virtual one, so it handles the two screens in a virtual desktop.

When I use this, the the pixmap is properly generated.

```
QPixmap pm = some_widget->grab();
```

But when I try this with the desktop widget, I get only a grey image.

```
QPixmap pm = QApplication::desktop()->grab();
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did not intend to use this, because it is obsolete, but I managed to do what I want only in this way:

```
QDesktopWidget* dw = QApplication::desktop()    
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow( dw->winId(), 0, 0, dw->width(), dw->height() );
```